# Why doctrine can't order by a virtual joined column and have setMaxResult and setFirstResult?

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following problem: 
I want to select some fields from an entity and to count for each selected row some rows from another table.

I run the following code:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ff')
               ->select('ff as feedbackForm, COUNT(ffa.id) as completedForms')
               ->leftJoin('AppBundle:FeedbackFormAction', 'ffa', 'WITH','ffa.feedbackForm = ff.id ')
               ->groupBy('ff');

    if (!empty($pageSize)) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($pageSize);
    }

    if (!empty($offset)) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
    }

    if (!empty($orderBy)) {
        if ($orderBy != 'completedForms') {
            $orderBy   = "ff." . $orderBy;
        }
        $qb->orderBy($orderBy, $direction);
    }
    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

The MAIN problem is that when I want to order by completedForms and the $pageSize and $offset is SET , doctrine can't handle the code, it says:

> Message: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sclr_12 DESC) AS doctrine_rownum, m0_.id AS id_0, m0_.start_date AS start_date_1, m0_.end_date AS end_date_2, m0_.active AS active_3, m0_.completed_required AS completed_required_4, m0_.section AS section_5, m0_.form_question AS form_question_6, m0_.count_completed AS count_completed_7, m0_.count_canceled AS count_canceled_8, m0_.created_at AS created_at_9, m0_.updated_at AS updated_at_10, m0_.deleted_at AS deleted_at_11, COUNT(m1_.id) AS sclr_12 FROM feedback_forms m0_ LEFT JOIN feedback_form_actions m1_ ON (m1_.feedback_form = m0_.id ) WHERE m0_.deleted_at IS NULL GROUP BY m1_.id,  m1_.created_at, m1_.feedback_form, m1_.user_id) AS doctrine_tbl WHERE doctrine_rownum BETWEEN 2 AND 6' with params [2]:  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)] [] []

But when I set ONLY $pageSize OR $offset and ORDER BY completedForms column I get the expected result. The problem is when I set both variables ($pageSize and $offset).